# In GoogleEarth can you have a photo overlay relative to ground?

Tags: overlay, kml, photo, google-earth

I'd like to have photo overlays that are clamped at a fixed height above ground level. Is this possible?

Are there any good work-arounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Right click on the image overlay and select Properties. Then in the altitude set the absolute elevation in meters. Image of the dialog box is here ([Image of Altitude Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7sql.png))